# Can't get XMPPReconnect to work on iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, reconnect

Seems like I am settings things up correctly but XMPPReconnect is not kicking in.. Am I missing something?

```
_xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
[_xmppReconnect activate:_xmppStream];
[_xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Comment: facing same issue.. Have you solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it only reconnects once the stream is connected.

Did you connect the stream after you've added the reconnect module?

Comment: hey @bert can you help me out from this..I am facing similar issue